# Timer0 overflow interrupt not working

Tags: interrupt, timers, arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4, avr-gcc

I try to use the Timer0 of an Arduino Leonardo (ATmega32u) to trigger an interrupt at regular intervals, using plain avr-gcc (not the arduino library). I try to blink the built-in LED as test, but it does not light up.

If I place a `PINC=0x80;` in the main function, the LED turns up, but not if I do it from the interrupt.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : The LED turns on with `TCCR0B = (1 << CS00);`, (no prescaler) or `TCCR0B = (1 << CS01)` (prescaler /8), but it does not with `TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02);` (prescaler /1024, what I want). At 16MHz CPU frequency the resulting frequency should be more than 15kHz, so I should see it instantly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    PINC = 0x80;
}

int main()
{
    DDRC = 0b10000000;

    //Start Timer 0 @ 15625 Hz
    TCCR0A = 0;
    TCCR0B = (0b101 << CS00);
    TIMSK0 = (1 << TOIE0);
    sei();

    while(true); // Avoid return from main
}
```

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: @jsotola I read the corresponding chapters of the processor datasheet and googled for a while, but I only found unrelated issues (e.g. using CTC mode or returning from main).

Comment: i misread .... deleting my comments .... you can delete yours

Comment: then you have to assume that the ISR is never called  .....maybe this may help  ....... http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Timer-Interrupts/

Comment: Sidenote: `0b101 <<  CS00` looks like bad code. Personally; I’d use `(1 <<  CS00) | (1 << CS02)`

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer here : https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/atmega32u4-arduino-leonardo-strange-timer-behavior

It seems that the USB connection generates higher-priority interrupts. I still don't know why the interrupts do work at higher frequency.

Solutions include powering the board from a USB charger or other power source rather than through the computer USB or adding the following code before the interrupt enable :

```
// Clear usb interrupt flags
USBINT = 0;
UDINT  = 0;
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{ // For each USB endpoint
    UENUM = i; // select the _i-th endpoint
    UEINTX = UEIENX = 0; // Clear interrupt flags for that endpoint
}
```

Thanks to those who helped me !

Comment: I think the interrupt handler is missing when the bootloader exits, so avr-gcc defaults to reset the board, which might result in higher frequency to switch on the led while at lower frequency the board is reset before the first interrupt.